# Powershell: How to grab base64 value from attribute of SearchResultEntry object?

Tags: powershell, ldap, base64, pki, tobase64string

My goal is to fetch the published CRL of a CA from an LDAP connection.
I have a function to search the LDAP (not Active Directory!), which returns a `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchResultEntryCollection` as expected.

```
$results = LDAPsearch "$_LDAP_server`:$_LDAP_searchPort" "cn=$CA,$_LDAP_searchBase" '(&(certificateRevocationList=*))'
ForEach ($element in $results){
    $element.Attributes['cn'].GetValues('string')
    $element.Attributes['certificateRevocationList;binary'].GetValues('string')
}
```

The above properly reads the `cn` attribute value of each element returned, however the `certificateRevocationList` is returned in a strange format which does not correspond at all to the Base64 string I expect (e.g. the one that can be read if you export your data to an LDIF file or if you use the Linux ldapsearch command)...

How can I get the actual Base64 value ?

Unfortunately, you can only pass 'byte[]' or 'string' as parameter to the GetValues method (a 'Base64String' option here would be useful to me, but well...).

Current output below (where `cn` value is correctly written but not `certificateRevocationList`):

[image: How the output looks like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve the raw CRL as `byte[]`, then convert to base64 yourself:

```
$crlBin = $element.Attributes['certificateRevocationList;binary'].GetValues('byte[]')
$crlB64 = [Convert]::ToBase64String($crlBin)
```

Comment: Thanks. I just need to pipe `| %{$_}` as `GetValues('byte[]')` returns an array (from which I expect only one value)... or simply select the first object: `GetValues('byte[]')[0]`. This works then.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the option I ended up using, much easier since my end-goal was actually to save the CRL as a file (and be able to parse it):

```
$crlBin = $element.Attributes['certificateRevocationList;binary'].GetValues('byte[]')[0]
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("$_localDir\CRL_$CA.crl",$crlBin)
```

This writes the actual CRL file in DER format (can then easily be switched to PEM using `certutil` or `openssl` if needed). My initial idea was to construct a PEM-formatted CRL file from the Base64 value extracted, but I was looking way too far...

I'm leaving Mathias's response as the answer since he actually best answered my question ; I didn't specify that I wanted a CRL file in the end.